# VBA Excel - Generates ID

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm trying to generate some student's ID and I'm having a hard time with it. Can someone help me if how can I automatically generate a student ID?

Here's what I'm thinking:

- There will be a code that will search for the last student ID similar to `NS0000000` in the student database sheet (STUDENTS_INFO), then it will just add one (1) every time the user will add students from Nursery or Junior Kinder.

The thing is:

1. I'm using an `UserForm` that is accessible in the `HOME` sheet while the data of students is stored in the `STUDENTS_INFO` sheet.
2. Some student's ID is not in the same format. It means that the user can enter a new set of student's ID if the student is from the Senior Kinder level. For Nursery or Junior, the format will be `NS0000000`. However, for the Senior Kinder, the format will be `402840000`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're looking for is basically a way to find the last non-empty cell in a column, and then add a number to it before you make it into the next student id?

Assuming your student ID's are in order, just get the last value. Assuming all the student ID's start with NS, take a substring of that, make it into an integer, then add 1 to it.
I would format the text as to keep all the leading zeroes and the NS value. The Excel Formula to do that is `=TEXT("NS", "")&TEXT(yourNumber, "0000000")`

Applying this and assuming your student ID's start on the cell B2

```vb
Sub makeNewID()
    ' Get all student IDs
    Dim studentIDsRange As Range
    Set studentIDsRange = Sheets("STUDENT_INFO").Range("B2", Sheets("STUDENT_INFO").Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    Dim nurseryJuniorIDs As Range
    Set nurseryJuniorIDs = Range("B2") ' Choose whatever top cell you want here, it just can't be an empty cell
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In studentIDsRange
    
        ' If NS is in cell, add to your range
        Debug.Print InStr(1, cell.Value, "NS")
        
        If InStr(cell.Value, "NS") > 0 Then
            If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                ' Add all the cells to new range
                Set nurseryJuniorIDs = Union(nurseryJuniorIDs, cell)
            Else
                ' Add just the first cell to range
                Set nurseryJuniorIDs = cell
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' Get last student at the bottom from all students
    
    Dim lastStudentIDRange As Range
    'Debug.Print nurseryJuniorIDs.Cells.Count
    Set lastStudentIDRange = nurseryJuniorIDs.End(xlDown) ' Range of the last cell
    'Debug.Print lastStudentIDRange.Value
    ' Get the number after the NS in that students ID
    
    'Debug.Print Replace(CStr(lastStudentIDRange.Value), "NS", "")
    
    Dim lastStudentIDNumber As String
    
    lastStudentIDNumber = Replace(CStr(lastStudentIDRange.Value), "NS", "") ' Get number without "NS"
    'Debug.Print lastStudentIDNumber
    ' Now increment that number
    Dim newStudentIDNumber As Long
    newStudentIDNumber = CLng(lastStudentIDNumber) + 1
    'Debug.Print CStr(newStudentIDNumber)
    ' Finally set the new student ID number into the spreadsheet underneath the last one
    Sheets("STUDENT_INFO").Range("B" + CStr(studentIDsRange.Rows.Count + 2)).Formula = "=TEXT(""NS"", """")&TEXT(" + CStr(newStudentIDNumber) + ", ""0000000"")"
End Sub
```

Sorry it's so verbose and each step seems redundant, I know this code can be much shorter but I decided to make it easier to understand

Edit: I added the nested if statements inside the `For Each` loop to look out for only the cells that have "NS", when it comes to dealing with the sheets just prepend the direct `Range("B1")` calls with `Sheets("STUDENT_INFO")`. My script still adds the new ID all the way at the bottom of the list, so while the numbers will be incremental, the ID formats will not. To change that simply change the last line to insert a new row underneath the last "NS" cell found, and then add your value there

Edit #2: This script is fully functioning for my test case where I have a column of some random IDs and some not, my previous code had too many errors so sorry about that, I should have used `CLng` instead of `CInt` because the numbers are way beyond the 100000 range at one point but it all works now.

Comment: Hello! I edited the question for more details. Can you help me with it?

Comment: So you're looking for the last NS cell? That's not too many changes, just filter through your range to find the last cell that has "NS" in the string, then add 1 to that

Comment: I'm having an error in this line `Set studentIDsRange = Sheets("STUDENT_INFO").Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))` that says `Subscript out of range`.

Comment: You need to prepend the Sheets("STUDENT_INFO") to ALL the direct Range("B2") calls

Comment: So `Set studentIDsRange = Sheets("STUDENT_INFO").Range("B2", Sheets("STUDENT_INFO").Range("B2").End(xlDown))`

Comment: I'm having a problem with this line `Set nurseryJuniorIDs = Union(nurseryJuniorIDs, cell)`, is the `cell` is equals to the student ID?

Comment: No cell is supposed to be the range of a cell that has a studentid with "NS"

Comment: Could you give an example table to work with?

Comment: Can I use `Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("STUDENTS_INFO")` rather than `Sheets("STUDENT_INFO")`?

Comment: Yes you could, and then use `ws.Range()` instead

Comment: Let me know if your script works now! I fixed it up

Comment: Can I have a chat with you? The codes keep receiving errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229483/discussion-between-da-mahdi03-and-cjvdg).